# Conditional split on various fields - moving data to the right field

Tags: sql-server, ssis, split, conditional-statements, derived

Im trying to fix a table with data that has been loaded by an ETL task. On the last 6 columns of the table there are some of the data has been placed in the wrong field because of multiple delimiters found in one field. So im trying to create SSIS conditional splits and derived columns to place them back in the right field.

This is the screenshot of the table data:
[image]

I found out that those addresses that is in FR is causing problem. So how can i:

1. Move and combine the City field data with StreetAddress
2. Move the StateProvinceCode data to City
3. StateProvinceName to StateProvinceCode
4. CountryCode to StateProvinceName
5. CountryName to CountryCode
6. Lastly to split PostCode data by the delimiter and move the data before the comma to CountryName?

Comment: You can do all of these with the derived column transformation.   You might also consider using a script transformation.

Comment: So how can i split the PostCode by the delimiter and move only "France" to CountryName and remove the delimiter?

Comment: You use a derived column, one that gets everything to the left of the delimiter.

Comment: Where can i put the Select statement where i will only change the those rows that belongs to a FR address and output into a flat file that is fixed of those errors above?

Comment: You would put it in the expression of the derived column.

Comment: Ok i've managed to put them in the correct field, but how can i update the derived column to the correct rows in the table?

Comment: By making the expression conditional on CountryName="FR".

Answer (score 0):

You can check following Update script
But before running on productive, you can better copy your data as backup

I did not use a SQL split function here but instead used the [SQL CharIndex function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) since your data has a simple structure

```
update AddressData
set
 StreetAddress = StreetAddress + City
, City = StateProvinceCode
, StateProvinceCode = StateProvinceName
, StateProvinceName = CountryCode
, CountryCode = CountryName
, CountryName = LEFT(PostCode, CHARINDEX(',',PostCode) - 1)
, PostCode = RIGHT(PostCode, LEN(PostCode) - CHARINDEX(',',PostCode) )
where CountryName = 'FR'
```

Comment: My requirement need me to use SSIS to get it sorted